# Is there a way to prevent "prefix inheritance"?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have an app that uses several prefixes and, while not frequent, it's also not unusual to add a prefix as we go along. What makes this painful is that the `Router::url()` method, by default, assumes that any url built should inherit the prefix of the current page if no prefix  is explicitly specified.

This appears to be a very deliberate action so I'm assuming that the majority of folks find it more useful than not, but I find it much more readable/maintainable to simply construct my URLs with prefixes where the URL needs one and leave it off when it doesn't. Long ago, I created `AppHelper::url()` to override `Helper::url()` which assumes nothing and only builds a URL with a prefix when it's explicitly requested and that's a huge help for links generated in views.

There is, however, another scenario that I'd like to override and haven't found a "clean" way to go about it. Consider an unauthenticated user who's bookmarked a link to an admin resource (e.g. `/admin/thing_that_needs_to_be_administered/some_action`). S/he clicks that bookmark, but isn't logged in so s/he gets redirected. Instead of being redirected to `/users/login`, s/he's sent to `/admin/users/login` which doesn't exist. Whoops.

Has anyone else found a way of doing this that they really like? The idea is to not have to explicitly set each prefix to false everywhere that redirection is done. That is just way too much maintenance when a prefix is added.

I think this gets easier in Cake 2, but we're running on Cake 1.3.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it Auth component that is doing the redirect? You may need to create a handler in your beforefilter of your app controller to handle the redirection if need be.

Comment: In this example, yes, but it could just as easily be a custom redirect if a page with another prefix is called without some necessary value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest trying this route if you have not already:

EDIT: Sorry, loginAction

```
<?php
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false );
?>
```

That will explicitly set the login url.

Comment: Yeah, and that's what I've done in the short term, but I have to explicitly set each prefix to false and then maintain that route each time a prefix is added. What I'm after is a way around that continued maintenance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of any other ways short of modifying the core.

Comment: Me either. Ideally, I'd like to extend the `Router` class and override its `url` method, but it's all static and called directly anyway, so that's not really an option. :-) Thanks.